# How are the compressor and turbine disks connected?

Tags: engine, turbine, engine-design

What is the typical way the compressor and turbine disks connected to (LP/HP) shaft ? How are the disks connected to each other  (e.g., curvic coupling, bolts or others ?)

Answer (score 4):

[image]

From The Jet Engine, Rolls Royce, issue 5: a compressor drum assembly. There are holes at the lower bit which attaches to the shaft, and another section of the book mentions hundreds of holes for bolts. These holes might be for fasteners.

Answer (score -2):

Typically the blades must not be too rigid but flexible. Ideally, the fir tree method is used to lock the blade root onto the disk, although there is its other counterpart.

Overall, you have the blades being attached to the disk, the disk attached to the drum and finally the drum to the spool/shaft. However, you must understand that each configuration or the methods used will vary from manufacturers to manufacturers and the type of engine under consideration. For example the centrifugal compressor and axial flow compressor. Hope this help.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the original question

Comment: In a gas turbine engine there are two types compressors and turbines*(dual spool engine)*. Overall, the compressor is connected or *coupled* to the turbine via a shaft. Hope this link helps *https://www.mikipulley.co.jp/EN/Products/FlexibleCouplings/about.html#:~:text=A%20coupling%20is%20a%20mechanical,error%20(misalignment)%2C%20etc.*

Comment: Yes but the OP question is HOW are they coupled. You just keep saying that they are coupled without giving any details.